# Jaxb2Marshaller schema validation doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, xsd

I experienced that Jaxb2Marshaller failed to validate my invalid XML against the XSD while doing the unmarshalling. 
I'm using Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE and Java 7.

Here is an example:

The XSD file: **fruit.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:attribute name="quantity" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:element name="fruit">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element ref="banana" />
                    <xs:element ref="apple" />
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="banana">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="quantity" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="apple">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute ref="quantity" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I generated the JAXB POJOs from this XSD with Spring Tool Suite to `com.testraptor.xml.jaxb` package.

My invalid XML file: **invalid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruit>
    <banana quantity="5" />
    <apple quantity="3" />
</fruit>
```

As you can see I broke the schema because there is a choice in the fruit tag and I used banana and apple at the same time.

My Spring configuration file: **app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd">

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="com.fruit.xml.jaxb" />

</beans>
```

The main class to test: **Main.java**

```
package com.fruit.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.fruit.xml.jaxb.Fruit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "app-context.xml");

        //--------------------------------SCHEMA VALIDATION IS OMITTED

        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Unmarshaller = (Jaxb2Marshaller) appContext
                .getBean("marshaller");
        Resource schemaResource = appContext
                .getResource("classpath:fruit.xsd");
        jaxb2Unmarshaller.setSchema(schemaResource);

        Resource xml = appContext.getResource("classpath:invalid.xml");

        try {
            Fruit fruit = (Fruit) jaxb2Unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xml.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("SCHEMA VALIDATION IS OMITTED:");
            System.out.println("Apple quantity is " + fruit.getApple().getQuantity());
            System.out.println("Banana quantity is " + fruit.getBanana().getQuantity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //--------------------------------SCHEMA VALIDATION IS PASSED
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema;
        try {
            schema = sf.newSchema(schemaResource.getURL());
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Fruit.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = (Unmarshaller) context.createUnmarshaller(); 
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema); 
            Fruit fruit2 = (Fruit) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("SCHEMA VALIDATION IS PASSED:");
            System.out.println("Apple quantity is " + fruit2.getApple().getQuantity());
            System.out.println("Banana quantity is " + fruit2.getBanana().getQuantity());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

When I run the code I get the following result:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-context.xml]
dec. 26, 2013 9:33:22 DE org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromContextPath
INFO: Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.fruit.xml.jaxb]
SCHEMA VALIDATION IS OMITTED:
Apple quantity is 3
Banana quantity is 5
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'apple'. No child element is expected at this point.]
    at ...
```

As you can see the Jaxb2Marshaller forgot to validate my invalid XML file while the Unmarshaller could validate it.

Can anyone give me a clue what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Tobias' answer worked for me. If it works for you too, can you mark it as the correct solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem when configuring `Jaxb2Marshaller` at runtime. The proposed solution to set the schema via Spring XML got me thinking: What's the difference between my code setting the property and Spring?

The answer is simple: `Jaxb2Marshaller` implements `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` which defines the lifecycle method `afterPropertiesSet()` and this method is called by Springs `BeanFactory` after the properties have been set.

So the Solution is to call `afterPropertiesSet()` after `setSchema()` has been used to set the schema property. Because in that method the schema property (which is a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` array) is actually used to set the internal schema field of type `javax.xml.validation.Schema` which is later used for schema validation.

**Example:**

```
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
Resource schema = new ClassPathResource("fruit.xsd");
marshaller.setSchema(schema);
marshaller.setContextPath("com.fruit.xml.jaxb");
// manually call Spring lifecycle method which actually loads the schema resource
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
// use marshaller...
```

Comment: Thank you!! I searched everywhere and this was the only place where I could find the correct answer for the exact context (schema validation using Spring, Spring's Jaxb2 marshaller and a schema file)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a validationEventHandler by calling setValidationEventHandler() and see if its been called ?

```
setValidationEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                     System.out.println(event.getLinkedException().getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
            });)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it but unfortunately adding the ValidationEventHandler didn't solve the problem and it seems the Jaxb2Marshaller forgot to call the hanleEvent() method because I can't see its sysout result on the console.

Comment: not sure that it would help, but can you try setting schema directly into xml config <property name="schema" value="classpath:com/fruit/xml/jaxb/fruit.xsd"/> instead of jaxb2Unmarshaller.setSchema(schemaResource);

Comment: The 'property' element can't be used in the oxm:jaxb2-marshaller bean definition because I got the following error:

Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm":class-to-be-bound}' is expected.